# Shifting to the argument of a setter

Tags: c++, sfml

Hello I want to use shifting operator `>>` to push something into an argument of function. To do it I can do the following, but is there any shorter and better answer?

```
int foo;
packet >> foo;
setFoo(foo);
```

The `>>` operator in `packet` takes an int. Also `setFoo` is constant and takes a constant reference of the integer. The `packet` is an instance of sf::Packet from SFML Network library.

Comment: What is ```bar >> foo``` supposed to do? Is ```>>``` the normal bitshift operator? if yes, where are you storing the result?

Comment: What do you expect ```bar >> foo``` to do?

Comment: Ah. Please include that in your question. Are we supposed to guess what ```bar``` is?

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, I thought that id does not matter that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sf::Packet` seems to have a member class called `sf::getData()`

You can presumably do `setFoo(*(int*)packet.getData())` but it isn't a "better" answer compared to your code.